# Testcontainer inside maven docker image in gitlab pipeline

Tags: docker, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, testcontainers

I am trying to run a gitlab pipeline to run my testcases using maven image. My testcases uses testcontainer. But somehow when I am trying to run testcontainer inside maven image it's not working. I tried couple of solutions provided on different online but nothing worked.

**.gillab-ci.yml**

```
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  # Instruct Testcontainers to use the daemon of DinD.
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  # Instruct Docker not to start over TLS.
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  # Improve performance with overlayfs.
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

test:
 image: maven:3.8.2-jdk-11
 stage: test
 script:
   - chmod -R 777 /var/
   - mvn -e test -f project_folder/pom.xml
```

Error I am getting is :

> 0:58:18.653 [main] DEBUG
> org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -
> EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy: failed with
> exception TimeoutException (Timeout waiting for result with
> exception). Root cause ConnectException (Connection refused
> (Connection refused))
>
> 10:58:18.654 [main] DEBUG
> org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -
> UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception
> InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket).
> Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
>
> 10:58:18.655 [main] ERROR
> org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Could
> not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration.
> Attempted configurations were:
>
> 10:58:18.655 [main] ERROR
> org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -
> EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy: failed with
> exception TimeoutException (Timeout waiting for result with
> exception). Root cause ConnectException (Connection refused
> (Connection refused))
>
> 10:58:18.655 [main] ERROR
> org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -
> UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception
> InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket).
> Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
>
> 10:58:18.655 [main] ERROR
> org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - As no
> valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
>
> 10:58:18.658 [main] ERROR ***********.***Service - Error in starting
> Container :  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid
> Docker environment.

Comment: You could try with `docker:19-dind` or check out [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27300#note_571697847) suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your service is not exposed correctly. I believe this is a TLS issue with your docker socket. Have you tried starting your DIND service explicitly disabling TLS?

```yaml
    variables:
        DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375 
        DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
        DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    services:
      - name: docker:20-dind
        alias: docker
        command: ["--tls=false"] # this right here
```